# Using a servlet to handle both multipart and normal requests

Tags: java, servlets, parameters, tomcat7, multipartform-data

I am developing a web application using servlet API 3.0 and AJAX. I've developed and tested locally (using run-jetty-run in Eclipse) and it seems to work fine. When I deploy to my Tomcat7 instance, however, I get a `NullPointerException` from a call to `getPart()`.

My setup is the following:

I have a run of the mill servlet (does not have the `@MultipartConfig` annotation).

In my `doPost()`, I am checking for an "activity" parameter which tells the servlet what the user was trying to do and determines the next course of action. I understand that in multipart/form-data requests these exist as part of the stream, so I've written a helper method to abstract that. In short, it tries to get it as a parameter, and if it doesn't find it, assumes it's a multipart request, so it calls `getPart("activity")` to get that part, and read the value from the part's InputStream.

Now, locally on RJR, I have no problem executing this code. The servlet is able to receive the "activity" parameter in both the normal requests and the multipart requests. I then deploy remotely to a Tomcat7 instance. After testing the application, the normal requests work, but when the multipart requests arrive, they throw a null pointer exception when I call `req.getPart("activity").getInputStream();`

I guess the crux of my question boils down to whether or not it is possible to properly receive both multipart/form-data as well as normal requests in the same servlet.

Also, this shouldn't make a difference, but when I deploy and test remotely, I am using an SSH tunnel to route traffic to the tomcat instance's port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a hunch, I tried adding the `@MultipartConfig` annotation in, and it works. This suggests different servlet containers treat the annotation differently.